# Open form to record seleced from double click on same record in datasheet form

Tags: forms, ms-access-2010

I've got a pair of forms that are both based on the same data table.  One is a single form with a better layout of all the onfo, the other is a datasheet.  I want to be able to double click on the project number in the datasheet form to open the details single form to that same record.
I've done it on a simplified practice db, but when I try it in my current db it opens the second form, but to a new record entry.  This form is one that was a template that someone else downloaded and modified for our purpose, so maybe there is something stored somewhere else that is interrupting the filtering.

I deleted a couple of macros that I thought might be interfering, made sure that the form properties are cycling all records and that on form load it isn't directed to a new record.  I can't figure out where else there is something preventing the form from being filtered for the selected record.  Here's the code I've used in the datasheet form:

```
Private Sub combined_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmTaskDetailsExisting", acNormal, , "SLRtaskID = " & Me.SLRtaskID

End Sub
```

Anyone have an idea what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered doing this with a split Form? You will have the Detailed view per record and the dataseet.

If you really want two independent forms due to your needs, your code looks ok. But two things may be happening:

- The value in Me.SLRtaskID is not correct. Put a breakpoint in the code and check it.
- There is code in frmTaskDetailsExisting that moves it to a new record when it is opened, regardless to the filter.

Comment: Yeah I considered the split form, but the details take up too much space which would block out most of the items in the datasheet list view.  I'll dig around more in the settings on the details form, though i've tried to do that and haven't found anything yet.

Comment: I tried creating a new form and copying all the objects into that in case there was something in the form properties messing this up.  When I redirect the on double click to this form it still opens to a blank record.  But if I view the properties it tells me that it is filtered on the record I want.  Is it possible something in the first form is affecting this?